# Hierarchical data with unknown depth itemsControl [UWP]

Tags: xaml, uwp, itemscontrol

I am trying to display a hierarchy of unknown depth in a panel with a itemsControl.
My data model looks like this

- Root object

  - |_ Pegs (Observablelist)

    - |_ Parts (Observablelist)

      - |_ Pegs (Observablelist)

        - |_...

I found this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt269384.aspx
 useful but I don't know how to take then next step and create a DataTemplateSelector that works. I found some old examples with a HierarchicalDataTemplate but that doesn't seem to exists in UWP.
Any ideas?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36711859/recursive-xaml-binding-data-templates-on-the-universal-windows-platform