# Recursive XAML binding data templates on the Universal Windows Platform

Tags: xaml, templates, recursion, win-universal-app

So I have a class Task which has a couple of properties and also can have a list Task objects ( child tasks ) inside it. I would like to recursively display each Tasks and their sub-tasks on the 'UWP'. Apparently 'WPF' had special 'UserControls' for that purpose according to this post: [Are recursive DataTemplates possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299915/are-recursive-datatemplates-possible)

but they don't seem to be available on 'UWP'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TreeView Control.

Here are the links to this project: [NuGet:WinRTXamlToolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinRTXamlToolkit.UWP/) and [GitHub:WinRTXamlToolkit](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit).

Install it in your project using Package Manager Console:`Install-Package WinRTXamlToolkit.UWP`

I've made a basic demo from your requirement. See codes below:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="TreeViewSample.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TreeViewSample"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:controls="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"
xmlns:data="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Data"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <controls:TreeView  ItemsSource="{x:Bind myList}">
        <controls:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <data:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>
                    <data:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubTasks}"></data:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </data:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:TreeView>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace TreeViewSample
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        public List<Task> myList;

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            myList = new List<Task>();
            var  taskA = new Task("TaskA");
            taskA.SubTasks = new List<Task> {
            new Task("SubTaskA"),
            new Task("SubTaskB"),
            new Task("SubTaskC")
        };
        taskA.SubTasks[0].SubTasks = new List<Task> {
            new Task("SubSubTaskA"),
            new Task("SubSubTaskB"),
            new Task("SubSubTaskC"),
            new Task("SubSubTaskD")
        };
        myList.Add(taskA);
    }
}

    public class Task
    {
        public Task(string name) {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        private String name;

        public String Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public List<Task> SubTasks { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot , it seems a lot of trouble to style it, but it's what I asked for, so I'll mark as answer