# How to bind a treeview in UWP to a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, binding, uwp, treeview, controls

I am currently working in UWP and I need to create a TreeView to store hierarchically a query of a service. example:
[Example I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDKAq.png)

I keep the information in a
`public ObservableCollection <Model> name_of_object {get; set; } = new ObservableCollection <Model> ();`

But I create the TreeView in the XAML and I do not see any way to do a Binding to the "SelectedItem" and "ItemSource" or any way to bring a query.

Tried this solution: 
[Recursive XAML binding data templates on the Universal Windows Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36711859/recursive-xaml-binding-data-templates-on-the-universal-windows-platform)

and I made it work with a query, it works for me, but nevertheless I need to manage other fields and I would like to be able to handle the one in this example:

[Windows Dev Centre: Tree View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view)

I want this, but with Bindings to ViewModel in UWP: [image: Example I want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the document you refered about [TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view), the Data binding to the ItemsSource property on TreeView and TreeViewItem is in Insider Preview build and SDK. You can follow the document [Tree view using data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view#tree-view-using-data-binding) part to achieve this function, but you should install the [latest Windows 10 Insider Preview build and SDK](https://insider.windows.com/en-us/), target you app on the insider preview build and test it in the insider preview build OS device.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Treeview from:

```
xmlns:muxc="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls"
```

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Category
{
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public ObservableCollection<Category> Subcategories {get; set;}
}
```

Then I bind the treeview with the itemsource:

```
 ObservableCollection<Category> Categories {get; set;}
```

of viewmodel.
And my xaml looks like this:

```
<muxc:TreeView SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="300" x:Name="CategoriesTree" 
      ItemsSource="{x:Bind _vm.Categories, Mode=OneWay}">
      <muxc:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local1:ProductCategoriesInfo">
                <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind SubCategories}" Content="{x:Bind Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
      </muxc:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</muxc:TreeView>
```