# Hierarchical View using the HierarchyId property from a DB object in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, entity-framework-core, hierarchical

I would like to know how to go about displaying my db object using the hierarchyid property in a tree or any type of hierarchy control in UWP.

So my object looks like this:

```
[Table("Foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long FooID { get; set; }
    public long ParentID { get; set; }
    public long RelatedID { get; set; }

    public HierarchyId HierarchyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Bar Parent{ get; set; }
    public virtual Tar Related{ get; set; }
}
```

It has a parent and a related item mapped with foreign keys but Foo as an item can also be a parent of another Foo item.

| FooID | ParentID | RelatedID | HierarchyId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 555 | 111 | /1/ |
| 2 | 555 | 222 | /2/ |
| 3 | 555 | 333 | /1/1/ |
| 4 | 555 | 444 | /1/1/1/ |
| 5 | 555 | 888 | /2/1/ |

So FooID: 3 is child of FooID: 1 and FooID: 4 is child of FooID: 3.

How can I display this in any hierarchical type manner in UWP?

Comment: Maybe check out the treeview comoonent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view

Comment: @TheTanic thanks for your input. I have looked at it before but have not yet seen if I can wangle it the way I need. I was hoping there might be a less complicated way of doing this. But as I said any kind of hierarchical structure (indenting the children) control will do the trick. If you can think of anything else please let me know.

Comment: Can u provide an example ui output u want to achive?

Comment: a TreeView, like you suggested, would work very nicely. But I also need the nodes to be individually selectable without affecting the children. I say the TreeView because it has nice indentations. But as I said any control would do (ListView, ListBox) as long as I can get it to indent the children items indefinitely. I would like to see clearly that some items are children of another item. Again thanks for the reply @TheTanic

This would work well but the level should come from the HierarchyId property: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850202/how-to-bind-a-treeview-in-uwp-to-a-viewmodel

Comment: You need split `HierarchyId` with `/`, if the array count more than 1, you need make children item for the fist item.

Comment: Hi @NicoZhu-MSFT. Thanks for your input. I'm using the MVVM pattern so I'm not entirely sure where this split would take place. At the moment I have, on the ViewModel, a list of Foo Models and all of them has a HiearchyId. I'm hoping for a control that takes a collection of Foo Models and then within the control it would then indent the children based on the parents via the HierarchyId.

Comment: There is no such control could render HierarchyId string as treeview directly, you need split it with new class that contain children, and then render it into TreeView.

Comment: So maybe try to create a control that inherits from TreeView and extend from there?

Comment: Yep, maybe you could custom treeview control and split HierarchyId string in the code behind. and use it in the xaml directly.

Comment: I'll try that thank you.